# When to use Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos over Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I see two packages Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos and Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB to connect and work with cosmos DB (SQL API). Both of them have CRUD functionality in them. I have confusion as to why there are 2 NuGet packages? Does both of them are used for different purposes? Are any of them deprecated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB is version 2.
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos is version 3

Use Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB when your project target .NETFramework.
Use Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos when your project targets .NET Core (.NET Standard)

Comment: Any official reference to these guidelines ?

Comment: Yes, take a look at https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/blog/new-for-developers-azure-cosmos-db-net-sdk-v3-now-available/ for a blog post about the new version v3 targetting .net standard

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB deprecated, so only use it if you want to suffer